# Use multiple Json files for each language translation by reactjs i18next translation

Tags: reactjs, json, nested

I have a json file named 'en.json' in my reactjs project in order to use i18next translation:

```
"Ascending": "Ascending",
"Descending": "Descending",
"All": "All",
"job-types": {
        "remote": "remote",
        "temporary": "temporary",
        "fulltime": "fulltime",
        "parttime": "parttime"
     },  
 ...
   }
```

I want to insert the "job-types" items in another json files then refer to it in my current 'en.json' file. Is it possible to use nested json files or is there any way to solve this problem? If yes, please how?

In i18n.js file I have:

```
  const resources = {
    en: {
      translation: translationEN
    },
    fa: {
      translation: translationFA
    },
    ar: {
      translation: translationAR
    }
  };
  
  i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
      resources,
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      debug: true,
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
      }
    });

 export default i18n;
```

translationEN , translationFA and translationAR are the imported .json files (to the i18n.js) for desired languages which are English, Farsi or Persian and Arabic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, in order to use the translation json files without being so complicated, I used two or more .json files for each language and concat them, without nesting them in the following way:

```
const resources = {
    en: {
      translation: { ...translationEN, ...translationEN1}
    },
    fa: {
      translation: { ...translationFA, ...translationFA1}
    },
    ar: {
      translation: { ...translationAR, ...translationAR1}
    }
  };
  
  i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
      resources,
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      debug: true,
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
      }
    });

 export default i18n;
```

The first json file:

```
{
   "Ascending": "Ascending",
   "Descending": "Descending",
   "All": "All", 
   ...
 }
```

and the other json file:

```
 {
    "job-types": {
        "remote": "remote",
        "temporary": "temporary",
        "fulltime": "fulltime",
        "parttime": "parttime"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to refer to a key in a JSON file, you first need to use `JSON.parse()` so you could traverse the object.

```js
const myResponse = JSON.parse(response);
const jobTypes = myResponse['job-types'] // dashed keys must be accessed through an index
```

If you need to reach the file, then link to it:

```js
const myResponse = await fetch('path/to/file.json');
const jsonBody = await myResponse.json();
otherObject.jobTypes = jsonBody['job-types'];
```

JSON doesn't support linking to other files, since it is just text. You can send the file's location as a value, but that's the farthest you can get.

Hope this helps.